# How do I safely cut holes into an old plaster wall that likely contains asbestos?

Tags: paint, plaster, asbestos, lead

I have a 1950 1.5 storey home with textured plaster walls, I understand the texturing was usually done with asbestos. The bottom layer of paint contains some lead as well; lab tests on my paint samples showed a concentration of 444ppm lead, which would have been the combined amount from two different color layers.

I need to cut some access holes into my attic crawl spaces to insulate them, and I also want to cut some holes to install an air exchanger.

What precautions should I take when cutting these holes to make sure I don't spread asbestos and lead dust around?

Comment: Keep the surface moist while you cut. Have someone stay behind you with a spray bottle misting your cutting area. PPE is also a good idea.

Comment: Just keep in mind that you're dealing with asbestos, not plutonium.  A number of trust funds were set up to benefit career asbestos workers, and this has caused an infinite number of lawyer ads trying to find those workers to put them on watch lists so if they get mesothelioma, the lawyers can jump on those trust funds. **The saturation of ads has made people worry about asbestos** FAR beyond what is actually warranted.

Answer (score 2):

Wear a mask. Wear eye protection.

Seal the room.

Dampen/wet/mist the surfaces you are cutting.

Use a vacuum as you are cutting.

Vacuum and wash down the room after.

Check and follow the rules/regulations for your locality for asbestos/lead removal.  Dumping in the backyard usually frown upon.